# Could not read json root name for type

Tags: android, json, spring, jackson

I'm using jackson and spring for getting an object from my api. I'm returning an array with 3 objects to an object called interviewsList which has the objects interviews, candidates and jobs. However in the json this is nested in wrapper called "interviews" since the path is /users/id/interviews. So it looks like this:

```
{"interviews":
     [[
         "interviews",[
             {"id":1...},
             {"id":2...}
          ]],
          "candidates", [
             {"id":1...},
             {"id":2...}
          ]]
          "jobs", [
             {"id":1...},
             {"id":2...}
          ]]
            ["status",201]
    ]}
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
     An exception occurred during request network execution :Could not read JSON: Root name 
    'interviews' does not match expected ('interviewsList') for type [simple type, class 
    com.example.model.InterviewsList]
```

Here's my container interviewsList:

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

    @JsonRootName(value="interviews")
    public class InterviewsList {

           private ArrayList<InterviewEntry> interviews; 
           private ArrayList<User> Candidates;
           private ArrayList<Job> Jobs; 

//getter and setters
    }
```

My request call

```
 response = restTemplate.getForObject(Config.WEB_SERVICE_URL + "users/"+userID+"/interviews", InterviewsList.class);
```

my api return

```
   render json: {interviews:interviewsList, candidates:candidatesList, status: 201}
```

Obviously I'm messing up the nesting. How could I solve this? Do I need to ignore the root or maybe there's something wrong with my render?

Comment: json format is incorrect. How did you create it?

Comment: That was probably a typo cutting from the browser window and pasting into SO, as I cut out a lot of the fluff. I probably trimmed off some brackets

Comment: @WillTuttle: then correct it! - you can not expect that one find a json mapping problem, when the posted json is not the one you have (of course you can omit unimportant parts, but you must not make it invalid)